# SQL Isnull is not working and returns a value even if it is a space

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

I am using SQL Server 2016 and came across an issue with the isnull function. The value in that field is a space but keeps getting selected, below is my code:

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE  isnull (field1,'')<>''
       AND field1<>' '
```

If I copy and paste from field1, it is one space ' '.

Thanks

Comment: Use `LTrim(RTrim(field1))` if you want to remove whitespace.

Comment: A blank string is a value...

Comment: A blank (`' '`) is different from an empty string (`''`) and an empty string is different from `null` (at least in sql server, Oracle is different).

Comment: I didn't get what exactly OP is trying to do ...

Comment: could be some other ascii character that is not visible?

Comment: Prabhat: The record should be excluded from the query but it is not.

Comment: What does ASCII(field1) return for that row? That will show you the ascii value of the first character.

Comment: Also for string datatypes you can simply use > '' and eliminate the ISNULL function which is non-SARGable.

Comment: yep, ISNULL is completely unnecessary in this query and has no effect on results

Comment: Sean: This field returns 9

Comment: If memory serves, char(9) is a tab char, not a space.

Comment: ding ding....we have a winner. It is NOT a space. space is 32, tab is 9. That would be why it is being returned.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your space is not normal space (hex 0x20, decimal 32)

```
select ASCII(LEFT(field1, 1), * From table
where  isnull (field1,'')<>''
```

Most likely it is one of

- Linefeed decimal 10
- Carriage return decimal 13
- Null decimal 0
- hard space decimal 160
- tab decimal 9 (as per comments on question from @SeanLange)

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution for this issue as:

```
SELECT ISNULL(NULLIF(field1,''), field2)
```

Comment: Bashar, ...Dude this solution rocks!!! Never knew about NullIf and I've been writing SQL for 20+ years?
Database/Table I'inerited has a Name and Description field, and sometimes Description is legit, but sometimes it's the empty string, and sometimes it's null. I wanted to standardize on replicating the name, at least, and ended up using a variant of your solution. Works for nulls and empty strings!
IsNull( NullIf( I.Description,''), I.Name) as 'Description'

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to put every possible combination in insert.. try this

```
Create table #t(Field1 varchar(100))
Insert into #t values 
(NULL), (' '), ('  '), ('a'),('')


select  field1 From #t
where LTRIM(RTRIM(field1)) <> ''
```

output :

```
field1
---------
a
```

Comment: As  Sean Lange had written in the comments, you could remove the LTRIM und RTRIM and just check `field1 > ''`

Comment: try `Insert into #t VALUES (CHAR(13)), (CHAR(10))`

Comment: Thanks @NenadZivkovic : learnt something new :) . Nik Bo...saw Sean's comment after posting. Thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

As we found out through comments and other answers (gbn's especially) there could be other invisible characters except space.

But that doesn't give you a solution how to write your query which could be something like:

```
where field1 NOT IN (CHAR(0), CHAR(9), CHAR(10), CHAR(11), CHAR(12), CHAR(13), CHAR(14), CHAR(32), CHAR(160))
```