# How to check if field is NULL and blank?

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I'm trying to remove the possibility of blank spaces by a value not existing in the database when creating the view for my lookup. The issue I'm having is that my `CASE` statement isn't working quite right when I'm trying to check for a `NULL` or blank value. It seems to work for those that are null but the blank doesn't seem to have as much luck. In this case I am trying to check for null or blank of `importantField`

```
CREATE VIEW Lookup4 AS
SELECT TOP 140000 CONCAT(no,
    CASE WHEN (importantField is null OR importantField  = '') 
        THEN '' ELSE ' ' + importantField END, 
            fieldname + ' ', anotherField2)  AS UNRELATEDFIELD, Code, 
    CASE NAME
        WHEN '101,,,,,' THEN 'value1e'
        WHEN '14,,,,,' THEN 'value3'
        WHEN '16,,,,,' THEN 'value4'
    END AS NAME
FROM  dbo.Lookup
```

Comment: You have a case _expression_, and _columns_.

Comment: Please check this question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45461543/sql-isnull-is-not-working-and-returns-a-value-even-if-it-is-a-space

Comment: with .length I get "could not be bound" error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are after

```
CREATE VIEW Lookup4 AS
SELECT TOP 140000 CONCAT(no,
    CASE WHEN (ISNULL(importantField,'') = '') 
        THEN '' ELSE ' ' + importantField END, 
            fieldname + ' ', anotherField2)  AS UNRELATEDFIELD, Code, 
    CASE NAME
        WHEN '101,,,,,' THEN 'value1e'
        WHEN '14,,,,,' THEN 'value3'
        WHEN '16,,,,,' THEN 'value4'
    END AS NAME
FROM  dbo.Lookup
```

Comment: isnull function requires 2 argument(s). Any ideas?

Comment: your tags were SQL and SSMS, which suggested MS SQL TSQL and SQL Server Management Studio.

ISNULL in TSQL has 2x arguments and my sample  has 2 x arguments 
ISNULL(fieldToCheck, ReplacementValueIfNull)

Comment: It seemed to have worked running it a second time without any changes. Might suggest there's issue with the data in the database, cheers.

Comment: If there was an issue with the data, wouldn't you have seen the same issue regardless of how many times you executed the query?

Comment: Had to add another space after the data. Found that 3k instances had an extra space in them for some reason even though the source file imported didn't have them. It's unusual that 3k / 180k had this happen to them but your query made it easy to sort through. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to check for null and not for empty strings then you can also use ifnull as you tried. But that is not suitable for empty strings too.

```
 SELECT IF(field1 IS NULL or field1 = '', 'empty', field1) as field1 
    from tablename
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to change:

```
importantField is null
```

with

```
IsNull(importantField)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE VIEW Lookup4 AS
SELECT TOP 140000 CONCAT(no,ifnull(importantField,'')<>'', 
            fieldname + ' ', anotherField2)  AS UNRELATEDFIELD, Code, 
    CASE NAME
        WHEN '101,,,,,' THEN 'value1e'
        WHEN '14,,,,,' THEN 'value3'
        WHEN '16,,,,,' THEN 'value4'
    END AS NAME
FROM  dbo.Lookup
```

Comment: isnull function requires 2 argument(s). Any ideas?

Comment: you can also use isnull same way as ifnull

Answer (score 0):

Minor changes according to your result

**Method 1:**

```
 Select *
    From dbo.Lookup
    Where IsNull(importantField, '') = ''
```

**Method 2:**

```
 Select *
    From dbo.Lookup
    Where (importantField is NULL or importantField = '')
```